# Adding an external link in APEX 5?

Tags: oracle-apex

We are currently creating a application, using APEX 5. I created a Google Doc, which I wish to link in the APEX application, but I am having some trouble doing so. Is there any way to link external webpages in APEX 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by simply surrounding your comment with an anchor tag, as follows

```
If you would like to access the feedback form, please <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> click here</a>
```